# Retrieving recent data with distinct column value - mongoid + rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have a `kevent` collection on mongodb that looks like:

```
_id,                user_id     action          created_at
43gy5235rwedwe      11          logout          2014-05-30 04:01:32 +0000
563gy5wwwedwex      11          running         2014-05-30 04:01:28 +0000
77gy5235rwedwe      26          logout          2014-05-30 04:01:22 +0000
3gy5235rwed65e      11          create          2014-05-30 04:01:20 +0000
4dgy5er35rwcwe      11          upgrade         2014-05-30 04:01:18 +0000
df5gy5s35rwwwd      43          poked           2014-05-30 04:00:32 +0000
fggy5235r322fs      29          login           2014-05-30 03:01:31 +0000
bhgy5235rwedfs      43          login           2014-05-30 03:01:30 +0000
ftweerw35rwedw      11          jumped          2014-05-30 04:01:29 +0000
we2y5s35rwedqq      12          created         2014-05-30 02:01:28 +0000
36gy5sa5rwesad      26          login           2014-05-30 01:01:27 +0000
36q4sa5rwesadw      11          login           2014-05-30 00:01:26 +0000
```

I am using mongoid (in rails 4) to retrieve *recent three* actions of *distinct* users. So the result should look like this:

```
_id,                user_id     action          created_at
43gy5235rwedwe      11          logout          2014-05-30 04:01:32 +0000
77gy5235rwedwe      26          logout          2014-05-30 04:01:22 +0000
df5gy5s35rwwwd      43          poked           2014-05-30 04:00:32 +0000
```

How to get that using mongoid?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out!

Sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE status = "A"
AND age = 50
```

Mongo:

```
db.users.find(
    { status: "A",
      age: 50 }
)
```

In your case you can do something like this:

```
User.any_of("$and" => [{action: "logout", action: "poked"}])
```

You can see every comparison to SQL to Mongo [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)